# MySQL Syntax error in php form

Tags: php, mysql

When I run a database query in a form I made I get the following error.

Database query failed
1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'release = "2013-05-27 19:33:29",platform = "PC",description = "Physics Puzzle Ga' at line 1
Query: UPDATE games SET title = "Osmos",genre = "Indie",release = "2013-05-27 19:33:29",platform = "PC",description = "Physics Puzzle Game",rating = "7",cost = "9.99" WHERE id=1

My code is posted below, I can't figure out where the error in the syntax is. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
    if ($id>0) {
    $query = 'UPDATE games SET ';
    $where = ' WHERE id='.prepareInsert($id);
} else {
    $query = 'INSERT INTO games SET ';
    $where = '';
}


$query .= 'title = "'.prepareInsert($_REQUEST["title"]).'"';
$query .= ',genre = "'.prepareInsert($_REQUEST["genre"]).'"';
$query .= ',release = "'.prepareInsert($_REQUEST["release"]).'"';
$query .= ',platform = "'.prepareInsert($_REQUEST["platform"]).'"';
$query .= ',description = "'.prepareInsert($_REQUEST["description"]).'"';
$query .= ',rating = "'.prepareInsert($_REQUEST["rating"]).'"';
$query .= ',cost = "'.prepareInsert($_REQUEST["cost"]).'"';

$query .= $where;

// do the query
$result = mysql_query($query)
        or      die("<p>Database query failed<br>" . mysql_errno() . ": " . mysql_error()."<br>Query: ".$query);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax error due to using a reserved word as a table or column name in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please do escape the column name `release` since it is a reserved keyword. If you have the privilege to change the structure of the table, please do change it.

Here are the [MySQL Reserved Keywords List](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

You need to escape it using backticks,

```
$query .= ',`release` = "'.prepareInsert($_REQUEST["release"]).'"';
```

Answer (score 3):

'release' is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL. You either need to enclose that field with backticks, or rename the column to something else.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape [reserved words in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) like `release` with backticks

```
$query .= ',`release` = "'.prepareInsert($_REQUEST["release"]).'"';
            ^-------^--------here
```